# Is there a way to prevent two 'home' addresses for a contact?

Tags: addresses

I'd like to prevent a single contact from having two addresses with the type 'Home' (or 'Work', etc.).  Is there a CiviCRM configuration, or an extension, that provides this functionality?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in the UI to create two home addresses. Form validation prevents it. Where are they coming from?

Comment: Imports perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, @Coleman. Should have guessed the UI would prevent this. Looks like they're created as part of a webform-civicrm form submission -- which I guess means they're created via API.  Need to dig further I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The form validation in the user interface will prevent this. So there's no need to have a setting that would prevent it.

But the API does not prevent it: you can,  for example, create a second Home address for a contact through the API.  There is no API configuration or option to prevent this.

Thanks @Coleman for pointing this out.